# woocommerce product categories shortcode pagination not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using **woocommerce product categories shortcode** [product_categories] and would like to have **pagination**,

because I'm displaying categories on product line page - and currently only 4 categories are being displayed.

I have added this short code also `[product_categories per_page="4" columns="4"]`. But it displaying only 4 categories. but no pagination displayed. I have tried  **WP-PageNavi plugin** and added below code in my themes functions.php

```
remove_action('woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
function woocommerce_pagination() {
    wp_pagenavi();      
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
```

It is not worked.Is there a way to **add pagination in woocommerce?**

Comment: Check out this link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120916/woocommerce-category-page-missing-paging

Comment: You can also check this https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/942

Comment: I have already tried this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120916/woocommerce-category-page-missing-paging). But it is affecting the normal woocommerce pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code. It worked for me:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
 if ( defined('WC_VERSION') ) {

// Set Pagination for shortcodes custom loop on single-pages.
// @uses $woocommerce_loop;

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hs_wc_pre_get_posts_query' ); 
function hs_wc_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Get paged from main query only
    // ! frontpage missing the post_type
    if ( is_main_query() && ( $query->query['post_type'] == 'product' ) || ! isset( $query->query['post_type'] ) ){

      if ( isset($query->query['paged']) ){
        $woocommerce_loop['paged'] = $query->query['paged'];
      }
    }

    if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
        return;
    }

    $query->is_paged = true;
    $query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
    $query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
}

/** Prepare Pagination data for shortcodes on pages
* @uses $woocommerce_loop;
**/
add_action( 'loop_end', 'hs_query_loop_end' ); 
function hs_query_loop_end( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
        return;
    }

    // Cache data for pagination
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'] = $query->found_posts;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'] = $query->max_num_pages;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'] = $query->post_count;
    $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'] = $query->current_post;

}


/**
* Pagination for shortcodes on single-pages 
* @uses $woocommerce_loop;
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_template_part', 'hs_wc_shortcode_pagination' ); 
function hs_wc_shortcode_pagination( $template_name ) {

    if ( ! ( $template_name === 'loop/loop-end.php' && is_page() ) ){
        return;
    }

    global $wp_query, $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( ! isset( $woocommerce_loop['pagination'] ) ){
        return;
    }

    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
    $wp_query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
    $wp_query->max_num_pages = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'];
    $wp_query->found_posts = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'];
    $wp_query->post_count = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'];
    $wp_query->current_post = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'];

    // Custom pagination function or default woocommerce_pagination()
    hs_woocommerce_pagination();
}   

/**
* Custom pagination for WooCommerce instead the default woocommerce_pagination()
* @uses plugin Prime Strategy Page Navi, but added is_singular() on #line16
**/
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'hs_woocommerce_pagination', 10);
function hs_woocommerce_pagination() {
    woocommerce_pagination(); 
}
}
}
```

https://gist.github.com/alexandreleroux/ba8aba53441967638c87